# scanf() is missing a first letter

Tags: c, scanf, fgetc, stm32f4

I want to use a scanf() function in STM32F401RE_NUCLEO with IAR compiler.

This is my overloaded fgetc function.

```
int fgetc(FILE *f) {
  char ch;
  while (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&UartHandle, UART_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET);
  HAL_UART_Receive(&UartHandle, (uint8_t*)&ch, 1, 0xFFFF);
  return ch;
}
```

And I use scanf in main function like below.

```
int n;
printf("[DBG] Input: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("[DBG] Output: %d\n", n);
```

If I type a "123" from terminal, then printed "23".

%d, %u, %f was same.

But, only %c works correctly.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have the same issue like the guy in the [mikrocontroller.net](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/232798) forum.

He needed to implement the functions *__write* and *__read* instead of *fgetc* and *fputc*.

Prototypes:

```
size_t __write(int Handle, const unsigned char * buf, size_t count);
size_t __read(int Handle, unsigned char * buf, size_t count);
```

May be also interesting for you: [How to override and redirect library modules](https://www.iar.com/support/resources/articles/overriding-and-redirecting-library-modules/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement __read function instead of fgetc. Remove the implementation of fgetc and use the following code.

Save following code into a file (eg. read.c) and add this file to your IAR project.

```
#include <LowLevelIOInterface.h>
#include "stm32l0xx_hal.h"

#pragma module_name = "?__read"

extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

int MyLowLevelGetchar()
{
  char ch;
  while (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart2, UART_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET);
  HAL_UART_Receive(&huart2, (uint8_t*)&ch, 1, 0xFFFF);
  return ch;
}

size_t __read(int handle, unsigned char * buffer, size_t size)
{
  /* Remove the #if #endif pair to enable the implementation */
#if 1  

  int nChars = 0;

  /* This template only reads from "standard in", for all other file
   * handles it returns failure. */
  if (handle != _LLIO_STDIN)
  {
    return _LLIO_ERROR;
  }

  for (/* Empty */; size > 0; --size)
  {
    int c = MyLowLevelGetchar();
    if (c < 0)
      break;

    *buffer++ = c;
    ++nChars;
  }

  return nChars;

#else

  /* Always return error code when implementation is disabled. */
  return _LLIO_ERROR;

#endif
}
```

You might need to include a different "stm32xxx..." header file based on your target MCU.